# Why are the instants at which maximum power delivered by the battery and maximum power delivered to the capacitor different?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, capacitance

When charging a capacitor, the rate at which the battery provides energy is maximum at $t=0$ but the instant at which power delivered to the capacitor is maximum is $t=CR\ln(2)$ (where $C$ is the capacitance of the capacitor and $R$ is the resistance of the circuit).

Why are they different? Shouldn't the power delivered to the capacitor be  maximum at $t=0$ when rate at which the battery provides energy is maximum?

Answer (score 1):

At the start of charging, the current is maximum and so is the power loss in the resistor $I^2R$. In the beginning of the charging process a lot of the power supplied by the battery is dissipated as heat in the resistor and very little supplied to the capacitor.

As time progresses, the current decreases and so less of the power supplied by the battery is dissipated in the resistor as heat and more and more supplied to the capacitor.

[image]

The power supplied by the battery as a function of time is $\mathcal E I_0 e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$ where $I_0$ is the initial charging current and $\mathcal E$ is the emf of the battery.

The power dissipated in the resistor is $I_0^2 R\, e^{-\frac{\color{red}2t}{RC}}$

The power supplied to the capacitor is $\mathcal E I_0 e^{-\frac {t}{RC}}\left ( 1- e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\right)$

You can see how rapidly the power dissipated in the resistor drops at a rate equivalent to half the time constant of the circuit.